# Creating unique index fails for unknown database exception in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My database has been working well for my application before this mysterious problem. I wanted to add an unique index in one table (listitems) for two columns (list_id and item_id). The table keeps track of which items are associated with each list and I don't want there to be duplicates in the lists.

So I wrote this database upgrade method which is called from onUpgrade(...)

```
private void upgradeTo3(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS '"+
        Contract.DATABASE_NAME +"'.list_item_unique_index ON "+ 
        Contract.ListItem.TABLENAME +
        " ( "+ Contract.ListItem.LIST +", " + Contract.ListItem.ITEM + ")");
}
```

And it gives me an error `"unknown database 'my_database.db'"`

I'm getting my database helper with this constructor which uses the same string as the SQL above, but here it doesn't throw an error. And I can access the database.

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Contract.DATABASE_NAME, null, Contract.DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Also if I open the DDMS in the Eclipse I can see that there is a file named 'my_database.db' within the application files.

Does someone have an idea why the database doesn't seem to exist in that SQL execution?

Answer (score 0):

Went back to the http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html and noticed that the name of the database is optional in the command. So I removed it from the command as it really should already know which database it is going to operate. And now it works.